# Undefined reference to wpa_ctrl functions in my C++ OpenFrameworks project. Need help integrating this c library

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, openframeworks

I'm working on a menu option to connect to wifi in my C++ application that is build using OpenFrameworks. I want to use the [wpa_ctrl](http://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/wpa__ctrl_8h.html) library but I can't get it to compile.

Code snippet:

NetworkWrapper.h:

```
#ifndef NETWORKWRAPPER_H_
#define NETWORKWRAPPER_H_

class NetworkWrapper {
public:
     NetworkWrapper():
private:
     struct wpa_ctrl* m_ctrl;
};
#endif
```

NetworkWrapper.cpp:

```
#include "NetworkWrapper.h"
extern "C" {
     #include "wpa_ctrl.h"
}

NetworkWrapper::NetworkWrapper() {
     m_ctrl = wpa_ctrl_open("wlan0");
}
```

Error:

```
***/NetworkWrapper.cpp:7: undefined reference to `wpa_ctrl_open'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried throwing around the include and using and not using extern "C" but it makes no difference seeing as wpa_ctrl.h is also enclosed in the extern "C" tag, albeit with #ifdef __cplusplus (which is defined, I double checked).

I'm pretty much out of ideas now. I should note that I tried enclosing wpa_ctrl.c in the extern "C" tags, which to my knowledge shouldn't compile(?). Which also gave the exact same result. This led me to manually compiling the wpa_ctrl library and copying to the obj directory but again: same result.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question, hope you can help!

*** EDIT ***
As per request my linking options (I trimmed it down a bit):

g++ -o bin/application_debug obj/linux64/Debug/src/main.o **[...]** obj/linux64/Debug/src/libs/wpa_ctrl.o **[...]** obj/linux64/Debug/src/common/NetworkWrapper.o **[...]** -Wl,-rpath=./libs:./bin/libs -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath=./libs -liw -L../../../libs/fmodex/lib/linux64/ -lfmodex -L ./bin/libs -lSDL -lSDL_mixer -lcurl ../../../libs/glfw/lib/linux64/libglfw3.a ../../../libs/kiss/lib/linux64/libkiss.a ../../../libs/rtAudio/lib/linux64/libRtAudio.a ../../../libs/tess2/lib/linux64/libtess2.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/linux64/libPocoNet.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/linux64/libPocoXML.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/linux64/libPocoUtil.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/linux64/libPocoFoundation.a  ../../../libs/poco/lib/linux64/libPocoNetSSL.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/linux64/libPocoNet.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/linux64/libPocoCrypto.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/linux64/libPocoUtil.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/linux64/libPocoXML.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/linux64/libPocoFoundation.a  -L/usr/lib64 -lz -lgstapp-0.10 -lgstvideo-0.10 -lgstbase-0.10 -lgstreamer-0.10 -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lxml2 -ludev -lsndfile -lopenal -lssl -lcrypto -lpulse-simple -lpulse -lasound -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lmpg123  -lglut -lX11 -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXcursor -ldl -lpthread -lfreeimage

Comment: Show us your linking options. Your linker is complaining that it does not know about the wpa_ctrl_open() function

Comment: Did you add the path to wpa_ctrl.h to your include-paths? Can you use other symbols defined in wpa_ctrl.h?

Comment: I added my linking options to my post. And it does recognize other symbols, for example I can define wpa_ctrl which works fine. It's just the functions that it is unable to find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I finally found what I was doing wrong. For future visitors:

I needed to add the following defines in my makefile:

```
-D CONFIG_CTRL_IFACE -D CONFIG_CTRL_IFACE_UNIX
```